# Get acceleration configuration of S3 bucket

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS SDK iOS v 2.5.0 to upload/download files to S3. I would like to use acceleration if enabled on the bucket. To test if acceleration is enabled I thought I could do the following, but it fails:

```
    AWSS3GetBucketAccelerateConfigurationRequest *accReq =   [AWSS3GetBucketAccelerateConfigurationRequest new];
    accReq.bucket=bucket;

    return [[[AWSS3 S3ForKey:region] getBucketAccelerateConfiguration:accReq] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

        return task;
    }];
```

The credentialsprovider is properly setup and working for the region. The error message I get is:

> `PermanentRedirect`The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.mybucketnamemybucketname.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

I thought from the [examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETaccelerate.html) that I did not have to specify endpoint for checking whether the bucket is accelerated or not? Am I doing something wrong in my request? Thanks. T

Comment: *The credentialsprovider is properly setup and working for the region.* And the region configured is us-west-2?  Is this a new bucket or has it been around for a while?

Comment: The region is us-west-2 and the credentials are working correctly. I connect with the credentials and loop over all buckets found. Its when I check each bucket for whether acceleration is enabled or not that I get the error above.

Comment: I should also have mentioned that the bucket has existed with acceleration enabled for a few weeks.

Comment: The docs link you mentioned doesn't show "specifying the endpoint" because it's implicitly assumed that you would be sending the request to the correct endpoint, and if sent to the so-called global endpoint (`bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`) it will arrive at the correct location via some automatic DNS magic unless the bucket is very new.  Does the iOS SDK provide a mechanism to inspect the generated API/HTTP request?  Does the bucket have any dots in its name?  That could also, potentially, be causing the SDK to use the wrong endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you can only check if the bucket is either enabled or suspended for acceleration if you use the s3-acceleration.amazonaws.com as endpoint? It seems to me that doing a general check whether a bucket is under acceleration using bucket.s3.amazonaws.com does not work. But it works to check for enabled/suspended if you are accessing through  s3-acceleration.amazonaws.com. But I may be doing this wrong....

Comment: If I check my bucket directly in the browser this works: https://mybucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/?accelerate Also, if I check a bucket that does not have transfer acceleration enabled the following gives: https://mybuckeaccnotenabled.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/?accelerate results in "S3 Transfer Acceleration is not configured on this bucket". So I have to use  "s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com" as my endpoint.

Comment: *So I have to use "s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com" as my endpoint.*  You're making a logical error, here. Because it works one way does not mean it doesn't work another way. If a bucket has transfer acceleration enabled, you can still query the `/?accelerate` subresource using bucket.s3.amazonaws.com or bucket.s3[-region].amazomaws.com.  Also, from the browser, for an accelerated bucket, you should get Access Denied when using the `s3-accelerate` endpoint, unless your bucket is misconfigured to make that value publicly visible or you are using a signed URL.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot Thanks for your answer. You were right about not needing to set the endpoint to check for acceleration. It turned out that I needed to set the region correct for each bucket when trying to establish whether the bucket was acceleration enabled or not. I thought the credentials required for this call were region independent as it is for 'listBuckets'. If you would make your comment into an answer I will accept it.